# Php Create array with increments days of week containing multidimensional array

Tags: multidimensional-array, concatenation, array-merge, days

I would like to create an array like this , and I'm lost with the syntax:
I can't nest the arrays together

```
$PeriodDayWeek = Array(
[monday] => Array
    (
        [start] => Array(
           [from] => Morninghour,
           [to] => Afternoonhour,
        ),
        [end] => Array(
           [from] => Morninghour,
           [to] => Afternoonhour,
        )
    ),
[tuesday] ...
until [sunday]
)
```

I have the beginning but it's not good:

```
$PeriodDayWeek = [];
foreach($EnglishDay as $Day):
                $Day = array(
                    "start" => array(
                        "from" => $_POST['Dayweek_JoMo_FrH_'. $Day] .'h'. $_POST['Dayweek_JoMo_FrM_'. $Day] ,
                        "to" => $_POST['Dayweek_JoMo_ToH_'. $Day] .'h'. $_POST['Dayweek_JoMo_ToM_'. $Day]
                    )
                );
endforeach;
$PeriodDayWeek = array_merge($Day, $EnglishDay);
$events_meta['periodevent_dayweek'] = maybe_serialize($PeriodDayWeek);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved :

```
$PeriodDayWeek =array();
foreach($EnglishDay as $day){

    $PeriodDayWeek[$day] = array(
        "start" => array(
            "from" => $_POST['Dayweek_JoMo_FrH_'. $day] .'h'.$_POST['Dayweek_JoMo_FrM_'. $day] ,
            "to" => $_POST['Dayweek_JoMo_ToH_'. $day] .'h'. $_POST['Dayweek_JoMo_ToM_'. $day]
        )
    );
        
}

$events_meta['periodevent_dayweek'] = maybe_serialize($PeriodDayWeek);
```